# Is wakelock static and if so, how do I manage multiple services/wakelocks in one application?

Tags: android, service, wakelock

I have a situation where I have 3 services that do different things and all need wakelocks.

At the end of their execution I would like to release the wakelocks, however, I'm concerned that a given service releasing its wake lock would undermine the behavior of a different service. So, the scenario I'm imagining is:

service A grabs wake lock and starts doing something

service B grabs wake lock and starts doing something

service A finishes and releases wake lock

what happens to service B at this point?

So, my underlying questions are:

a) is this something to worry about or does Android automatically manage this for me behind the scenes (my assumption is it does not)?

b) what's the best way to make sure that either the wake lock persists if any of the services are not done, or to grab separate wakelocks that won't undermine one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the best way to make sure that either the wake lock persists if any of the services are not done

Call `setReferenceCounted(true)` on the `WakeLock`. That's already set up by default, but you could call it again if you want.

Comment: ah... the reference counting part of this whole mechanism is one that I was unclear on and will obviously serve my purpose perfectly without explicitly calling a redundant boolean setter. Thanks, as always.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Yup. Usually, you want reference-counted `WakeLocks`, which is why that's on by the default. In `WakefulIntentService`, I *really really really* want a reference-counted `WakeLock`, so I go ahead and call the setter anyway, just in case Google changes the default. Presumably, there are scenarios in which you might not want a reference-counted `WakeLock`, though I can't think of an example off the top of my rather balding head.